# How to add a variable to an array

Tags: java, arrays, variables, loops, random

I am trying to set the value in an array to a variable. Here is my code:

```
//init the array as a float
//I have tried to put a value in the brackets, but it returns a different error.
//I initialized it this way so I could call it from other methods
private float[] map;

// generate a "seed" for the array between 0 and 255
float x = generator.nextInt(256);
int n = 1;
// insert into the first 25 slots
while(n <= 25) {
    // here's my problem with this next line
    map[n] = x;
    double y = generator.nextGaussian();
    x = (float)Math.ceil(y);
    n = n + 1;
}
```

I marked the line with my error, the error returned is: "uncaught exception thrown in...". What am I doing wrong??? Thanks in advance.

EDIT-----

Here's the whole exception:

```
    Uncaught exception thrown in Thread[LWJGL Renderer Thread,5,main]
```

I'm using y to generate a random gaussian, then converting it into a float value and changing x into that float value

I'm pretty sure that It's that line, because that's what my compiler told me.

Comment: Can you post more of the exception.  Can you also show how map is defined?

Comment: what is `map`? what is `y` for?

Comment: what's the type of "map"? what's the whole message for the error? May not be the next line? (generator.nextGaussian();)

Comment: Not directly relevant, but any reason you're not using a `for` loop for this?  More relevant, please post what Gray said, the `map` definition and the *whole* exception.

Comment: Far too localized. How do I know it's too localized? There is *no way to write a good title for this question*. 1) **read the exception, post the exception, use the exception in some meaningful way to solve the problem** 2) post all applicable code. Also, as a nit, it's not possible to add a variable to an array -- only *values* can be added.

Comment: Well, -1 for lack of actually listening to comments and updating the question.

Comment: just read comments, updated question

Comment: Wow - I can't believe this question was downgraded because he never updated it in 14 minutes of it being posted. Though the exception would've been nice, some newer posters (check his score) need some help so maybe try to be constructive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that you get one of two exceptions:

1. You are getting a `NullPointerException` because have initialized map to `null`. Assign a non-null value using for example:

   ```
   private float[] map = new float[25];
   ```
2. You are getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because you are using 1-based indexing instead of 0-based indexing.

Change this:

```
int n = 1;
while(n <= 25) {
    // etc..
    n = n + 1;
}
```

To this `for` loop:

```
for (int n = 0; n < 25; ++n) {
    // etc..
}
```

Comment: @JAW1025: So... are you going to tell us what the type of the exception you get is? My answer is only my best guess. You have posted too little information for me to be sure.

Comment: Just tried it, perfect answer, fixed EVERYTHING thanks! (and sorry for not being clear the first time around.)